# Script stops execution when faces an error

Tags: powershell

I have a master script `master.ps1` which calls two scripts `One.ps1` and `Two.ps1` like:

```
&".\One.ps1"
&".\Two.ps1"
```

When the `One.ps1` script has an **error**, the execution gets **stopped** without continuing the execution of `Two.ps1`

How to **continue** execution of `Two.ps1` even if there is an error in `One.ps1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Martin is correct assuming that the success or failure of `.\One.ps1` does not impact `.\Two.ps1` and if you don't care about logging or otherwise dealing with the error. but if you would prefer to handle the error rather than just continue past it you could also use a [Try{}Catch{}](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/05/weekend-scripter-using-try-catch-finally-blocks-for-powershell-error-handling/) block as below to log the error (or take any other action you would like in the `Catch{}`)

```
Try{
  &".\One.ps1"
} Catch {
  $error | Out-File "OneError.txt"
}
Try{
  &".\Two.ps1"
} Catch {
  $error | Out-File "TwoError.txt"
}
```

Other ways to format this but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `$ErrorActionPreference` to *continue*:

```
Determines how Windows PowerShell responds to a non-terminating
error (an error that does not stop the cmdlet processing) at the
command line or in a script, cmdlet, or provider, such as the
generated by the Write-Error cmdlet. 

You can also use the ErrorAction common parameter of a cmdlet to 
override the preference for a specific command.
```

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx).

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'continue'
```

---

***Note***: As a best practice I would recommend to first determine the current error action preference, store it in a variable and reset it after your script:

```
$currentEAP = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'continue'
&".\One.ps1"
&".\Two.ps1"
$ErrorActionPreference = $currentEAP
```